# How can you split text to columns if there are multiple delimiters of the same type in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a column that has dates, days, and times in it. I need to split out just the time but there are multiple hyphens, how can I achieve this? Below is what I have.

| Recording Time |
| --- |
| Monday July 11 2022 - 8:00am - 10:00am |

This is what I want

| Monday July 11 2022 | 8:00am - 10:00am |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also try:

```
=left(A1,find("-",A1,1)-2)
```

And

```
=mid(A1,find("-",A1,1)+2,len(A1))
```

Which will split either side of the first `-`.

Check for the formatting for your results.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to temporarily avoid the second hyphen with some find and replace actions:

1. find and replace in your relevant column of times/dates: `m -` replace with `m +`
2. Text-to-columns split on the first hyphen
3. find and replace in the times column: `m +` replace with `m -`

The use of the `+` character is simply a convenient choice here.

Answer (score -1):

If the columns are going to be consistent, I would use the "Fixed width" option instead of "Delimited". You can tell it exactly where you want the field to be split, specify the formatting for each new column, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).